# Where to bind selection change to ListAdapter in .kv

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

In the following kv section:

```
TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab2
        text: 'VIEW'
        on_press: root.viewInit()
        ListView:
            id: view_list
            adapter: 
                ListAdapter(
                data= root.valid_views,
                selection_mode='multiple',
                allow_empty_selection=True,
                cls=ListItemButton)
```

Where do I insert `on_selection_change: root.somefunc()` to bind and catch the selection change event in ListAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab2
        text: 'VIEW'
        on_press: root.viewInit()
        ListView:
            id: view_list
            adapter: 
                ListAdapter(
                data= root.valid_views,
                selection_mode='multiple',
                allow_empty_selection=True,
                cls=ListItemButton,
                on_selection_change = root.somefunc())
```